# Zxing Format Exception in Scanning PDF and converting to Buffered Image to Decode QR

Tags: java, pdf, zxing, qr-code

I'm having problem with getting continuous successful QR decoding after PDF conversion. I keep getting,

> "Exception in thread "main" com.google.zxing.FormatException."

My conversion attempts were done in:
PDFBox

```
public static BufferedImage convertPDFtoBufferedImageType2(String PDFPath) throws IOException{

    PDDocument document = null;
    try {

        document = PDDocument.load(PDFPath);
        PDPage firstPage = (PDPage) document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().get(0);
        return firstPage.convertToImage();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PDF_Utility.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return null;
    } finally {
        if(document != null)
            document.close();
    }
}
```

Second Attempt with ghost4j

```
public static BufferedImage convertPDFtoBufferedImage(String PDFPath) throws IOException, RendererException, DocumentException{

    System.setProperty("jna.library.path", "C:\\Program Files\\gs\\gs9.16\\bin\\");

    PDFDocument document = new PDFDocument();
    document.load(new File(PDFPath));
    SimpleRenderer renderer = new SimpleRenderer();
    renderer.setResolution(300);
    List<Image> imgs = renderer.render(document);
    Image im = imgs.get(0);

    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage
        (im.getWidth(null),im.getHeight(null),BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics bg = bi.getGraphics();
    bg.drawImage(im, 0, 0, null);
    bg.dispose();
    return bi;
}
```

My QR Decoder is:

```
public static String readQRCode(BufferedImage image, String charset, Map hintMap) 
                throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, NotFoundException, ChecksumException, FormatException {
        Result qrCodeResult = null;
        BinaryBitmap binaryBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(
                        new HybridBinarizer(new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(image)));
        try{
            qrCodeResult = new com.google.zxing.qrcode.QRCodeReader().decode(binaryBitmap,hintMap);
        }catch(NotFoundException | FormatException e){ //attempt without hints
            qrCodeResult = new com.google.zxing.qrcode.QRCodeReader().decode(binaryBitmap);
        }
        return qrCodeResult.getText();
}
```

And the reason why I called decode twice was because sometimes the "try harder"

```
hintMap.put(DecodeHintType.TRY_HARDER, Boolean.TRUE);
```

actually didn't catch the QR code, but the default did. 
Anyways, these code snippets do catch most of my QR scans from a pile of documents, but there are times where it does not catch it at all. I even attempted to write it out as an image and then re-read it in:

```
ImageIO.write((RenderedImage) im, "png", new File("/path/to/my/img.png"));
```

Interestingly, http://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx does decode that output image, but my code couldn't.
I also tried different charset:
CHAR_SET = "UTF-8"; and CHAR_SET = "ISO-8859-1";

By getting Format Exceptions, the code was found, but "did not conform to the barcode's format rules. This could have been due to a mis-detection."

Apology for the messy code, but those attempts have gained majority of successful scans. 9/10 rate? Interestingly, sometimes another scanned copy of the same doc worked. Any help/advice/crazy voodoo combination is appreciated! Thanks!

EDIT: I got a sample (after whiting out the contents around. The real image has contents! Zxing website was able to catch this QR code too (with and without contents! (My program already ignored the other 1Ds at this same format and those with contents).
[image: QR Code]

Comment: In those cases where you have problems with the barcode, did you get a decent image? in PDFBox, the default rendering size might not be enough. Try experimenting (it will be slower!) with 200 or 300dpi. Alternatively, try the ExtractImages example, so that you get the images "as is".

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Thanks, it worked and I posted it as the answer. For ExtractImages, it seems like this is only used under command line? https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/1.8.2/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/ExtractImages.html Anyways...how do I give you rep point? Or do I not have enough to give you any...

Comment: No problem, just write my name correctly (two "r", not two "e"), that is the most important :-) while the extractImages is a command line utility, you should have a closer look at the source code so that you can use it for your purpose. It goes like this: page => resources => XObjects => XImageObjects => use barcode scan.

Comment: Btw @TilmanHausherr, I tried the extract image process as followed from above after grabbing the code from http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox/1.0.0/org/apache/pdfbox/ExtractImages.java. It produced a .jpg image but I still got a format exception. But overall, my scan success rate has been up to 24/25! (This is another img that failed to scan, but still worked on zxing website). Attempting to increase resolution/dpi did not yet seem to help. (I increased it up to 600+ already).

Comment: That link is outdated, try also the ExtractImages.java example in the source code. Also avoid saving and reloading the image, try to get the BufferedImage from the image XObject. (getRGBImage) An even better method (if your barcodes are in a JPeg Image) is also in the source code download of ExtractImages.java, search for "getPartiallyFilteredStream", which allows you to get the exact jpeg image that is in your PDF. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

@Tilman Hausherr pointed out for the PDFBox default rendering size as low so I changed the default to 300dpi as he suggested. Overall, it worked for my case but definitely slowed down the speed. Will need to tweak my algorithm to run both a fast and this slower one as a backup.

```
return firstPage.convertToImage(BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR, 300);
```

EDIT: Increased the success rate of catching barcodes, but did not successfully catch all. Increasing the dpi does not help.

Comment: *slowed down* - if the bar code is included in the PDF as bitmap image, you might *extract* the images and scan then separately instead of rendering the whole page As image to scan.

Comment: @mkl In terms of extraction, would the image need to be pinpointed? The only problem with that is the barcode is a sticker and whoever put the sticker on will possibly put it anywhere on that paper. Otherwise, I think I'd give that a try too.

Comment: You can extract the bitmap images on a page whereever they are used. If I were you, I'd try that approach, too.

Comment: @mkl I did subImage of the barcode page so it's a little faster now. Production told me the barcode will always be on the top right corner.
image.getSubimage(image.getWidth()/2, 0, image.getWidth()/2, image.getHeight()/2);